# Pagination in Vue js & Laravel loses track of page after submitting form

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, pagination

I have a problem keeping track of the current page of the pagination, after submitting a form.

I have a Web App, built in vue js and laravel. The issue is with the part of the API that administrates user. The Laravel controller gets and paginates all users from the database, and then vue js displays the paginated results. The webpage also lets the moderator open a form and edit each individual user's info.
The problem is that the form submission resets the page variable and after the page is reloaded it lands on page 1 instead of the page on which the pop-up form was opened.
I guess this is a matter of passing a variable called "page" with the form, but I'm a newbie with vue js and can't get it to work :(

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return User::orderBy('name','asc')->paginate(10);
     }
```

Vue js component, displaying the pagination buttons

```
<div class="card-footer">
     <pagination :data="users" @pagination-change-page="getResults"></pagination>
</div>
```

Vue js component, submitting an "edit user" form

```
<form @submit.prevent="editmode ? updateUser() : createUser()">
    ... (generic form code)
    <button v-show="editmode" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">update</button>
</form>
```

Vue js methods

```
methods:{
            getResults(page = 1) {
                axios.get(base_path+'/admin_api/user?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.users = response.data;
                    });
            },
            loadUsers(page = 1){

                this.$Progress.start()
                    axios.get(base_path+'/admin_api/user?page=' + page).then(({data}) => (this.users = data));
                this.$Progress.finish()
            },
           updateUser(){
             this.$Progress.start()
             this.form.put(base_path+'/admin_api/user/'+this.form.id)
                 .then(()=>{
                     Fire.$emit('AfterCreate')
                     $('#addNewModal').modal('hide');
                     toast({
                         type: 'success',
                         title: 'Benutzer erfolgreich aktualisiert'
                     })
                     this.$Progress.finish()
                   })
                 .catch(()=>{
                     this.$Progress.fail()
                 })
          }
        },
}
```

```
created(page=1){
             ...
              this.loadUsers(page)
              Fire.$on('AfterCreate',()=>{
                  this.loadUsers(page)
              })
              Fire.$on('AfterDelete',()=>{
                  this.loadUsers(page)
              })
}
```

Changing the default page=1 to a different number successfully changes the default. But the wanted results of staying on the current page didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, does "opening" the edit user mode navigate to a new **laravel** route? meaning, does the page refresh when you open a specific user?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño no it opens a js pop-up on the same page. It only refreshes on form submission. closing the pop-up without submission (canceling) stays on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your form fields are using `v-model` or similar bindings with vue (as they should so you can leverage from Vue's features), you can remove the `@submit` event on the `form` html tag and let vue handle the click event on the button.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" v-model="user.firtName"/>
    ... (generic form code)
    <button v-show="editmode" type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="editmode ? updateUser() : createUser()">update</button>
</form>
```

Note that the `type` is now button instead of submit. After the `updateUser` or `createUser` are done doing their thing, just emit an event from the modal to the parent component to dismiss the modal.

```
updateUser(){
    this.$Progress.start()
    // Use Axios HERE, something like
    axios.put(base_path+'/admin_api/user/'+this.form.id, this.user)
        .then(()=>{
            // ...
        })
        .catch(()=>{
            this.$Progress.fail()
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.$emit('closeModal');
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately this still doesn't exactly solve the issue. With axios it's suddenly not working at all. Keeping this.form.put but changing the rest results in it staying on the correct page but not refreshing it (or updating the view asynchronously) - so the user's details aren't visibly updated until refreshing the page.
I tried now using  this.loadUsers(this.page) inside the put.then() but that just goes to the default page again :(

Comment: I now see that using axios.put gives me a 422 unprocessable entity error. Couldn't figure out yet how to correct it...

Comment: You'll need to manually refresh the list or the record, no need to reload because when you reload, you lose the state of `this.page`.  If your user is not updated in the table it can be due to Vue preventing a refresh on the object for component reusability, on `loadUsers` you can try `.then(({data}) => this.$set(this.users, data));`